# Merge partition with partition on the left

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have the following partitions

[image]
I have no problem translating the image, as it is in Dutch, but it should be self-explanatory.

I want to merge `/dev/sda8` with `/dev/sda5` without losing data from `/dev/sda5`

I've looked around but could not find a good answer.

As you can see, `sda8` is not mounted and it's contents can be lost no problem.

When I remove that partition and try to move `sda5`, it won't let me. I can't move that partition to the left for some reason.

Comment: You have to use live installer. You cannot modify mounted partitions & little key icon says it is mounted. I do not like moving left as any interruption power failure, impatient user, etc totally corrupts it. So have good backups.  I prefer to have smaller system partitions like 25GB and larger /home or data partition(s). I use a data partition, but newer users find setting up /home easier. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

As [oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred) pointed out:

You have to use live installer. You cannot modify mounted partitions & little key icon says it is mounted. I do not like moving left as any interruption power failure, impatient user, etc totally corrupts it. So have good backups. I prefer to have smaller system partitions like 25GB and larger /home or data partition(s). I use a data partition, but newer users find setting up /home easier. [Question #743095](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu)

Comment: but how can you achieve this merging of partitions on the left?